# Windows Search refuses to start

Tags: windows-7, services, windows-search

I was working on my tablet the other day, and OneNote 2007 started to complain that it was unable to index my notebooks since the search service was offline. I figured it had crashed or a program had killed it off for one reason or another, so I ended up rebooting the computer.

After the reboot, I went back to working in OneNote and received the search failure message again. I opened up the 'Services' panel and found the Windows Search service. When I attempted to start it up I was greeted with this message:

```
Windows could not start the Windows Search service on Local Computer.
Error 1392: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.
```

I searched around for a solution, but couldn't find a clear answer. I have never encountered this type of issue in Windows 7, and I am not sure how to safely/correctly repair this problem. I am attaching a few screen shots of the error dialog from Windows, and three related events from event viewer:

[image: Image01]

[image: Image02]

[image: Image03]

[image: Image04]

[image: Image05]

Any tips? Where should I start? I'm really lost here.

Comment: Have you tried running a `chkdsk /r`?

Comment: I had to go to the Repair mode from the F8, and use the console feature to run a `chkdsk [drive] /R`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by Hello71 in his comment to your question, try `chkdsk /r` first.

You can repair corrupted system files by entering `sfc /scannow` in the console.

If possible, in Search Indexing you can try to click Advanced and to rebuild the (corrupted?) Index Cache.

Comment: A `chkdsk /R` worked, but I had to go to Recovery Mode after hitting F8 on boot.

Answer (score 2):

See if this article helps:

[How to Fix the Start Error for Windows Search Service to Enable the Index in Vista](http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/85803-index-windows-search-service.html)